# Json string is null

Tags: php, json, web

I have the following Json page:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: json; charset=utf-8');
    $lottery = array(
        array(
            "id" => 0,
            "navn" => "Vind telefon",
            "udgiver" => "Telia",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind en Iphone 5 ved at gætte 1 spørgsmål",
            "tilmeldte" => 89,
            "startdate" => "10-04-2013",
            "enddate" => "30-06-2013"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 1,
            "navn" => "Fri taletid",
            "udgiver" => "Telmore",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind et års forbrug af fri data og fri taletid",
            "tilmeldte" => 701,
            "startdate" => "03-03-2013",
            "enddate" => "10-06-2013"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 2,
            "navn" => "Vind 5000 kr.",
            "udgiver" => "Bilka",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind et gavekort på 5000 kr til bilka.",
            "tilmeldte" => 101,
            "startdate" => "10-05-2013",
            "enddate" => "01-07-2013"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 3,
            "navn" => "Fri vin",
            "udgiver" => "Føtex",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind et års forbrug af vin",
            "tilmeldte" => 391,
            "startdate" => "01-04-2013",
            "enddate" => "10-07-2013"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 4,
            "navn" => "Vind et TV",
            "udgiver" => "El-giganten",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind et 60\" LED tv til stuen",
            "tilmeldte" => 22,
            "startdate" => "01-04-2013",
            "enddate" => "22-07-2013"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 5,
            "navn" => "Vind en telefon",
            "udgiver" => "Samsung",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind en Galaxy S4 4g telefon",
            "tilmeldte" => 784,
            "startdate" => "10-04-2013",
            "enddate" => "30-07-2013"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 6,
            "navn" => "Gratis Vand",
            "udgiver" => "Aqua D'or",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind et helt års forbrug af vand og dansk vand",
            "tilmeldte" => 345,
            "startdate" => "01-03-2013",
            "enddate" => "18-07-2013"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 7,
            "navn" => "Fri Adwords",
            "udgiver" => "Google",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind adwords kuponner til en værdi af 10.000",
            "tilmeldte" => 22,
            "startdate" => "10-02-2013",
            "enddate" => "22-08-2013"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 8,
            "navn" => "Morgenmads produkter",
            "udgiver" => "Kellogs",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind et helt års forbrug af kellogs produkter",
            "tilmeldte" => 111,
            "startdate" => "01-05-2013",
            "enddate" => "10-09-2013"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 9,
            "navn" => "Vind tøjj for 10.000",
            "udgiver" => "Jack & Jones",
            "beskrivelse" => "Vind et gavekort til Jack & Jones på 10.000",
            "tilmeldte" => 33,
            "startdate" => "03-05-2013",
            "enddate" => "01-10-2013"
        )
    );
    //id, navn, udgiver, beskrivelse, tilmeldte, startdate, slutdate
    echo json_encode($lottery);
```

All of the fields works fine but one!

the field `beskrivelse` returns is null when i open my json.

Here is a link to [My Json](http://www.marcrasmussen.dk/Pages/json.php)

And here is the json in plain text

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "navn": "Vind telefon",
        "udgiver": "Telia",
        "beskrivelse": null,
        "tilmeldte": 89,
        "startdate": "10-04-2013",
        "enddate": "30-06-2013"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "navn": "Fri taletid",
        "udgiver": "Telmore",
        "beskrivelse": null,
        "tilmeldte": 701,
        "startdate": "03-03-2013",
        "enddate": "10-06-2013"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "navn": "Vind 5000 kr.",
        "udgiver": "Bilka",
        "beskrivelse": null,
        "tilmeldte": 101,
        "startdate": "10-05-2013",
        "enddate": "01-07-2013"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "navn": "Fri vin",
        "udgiver": null,
        "beskrivelse": null,
        "tilmeldte": 391,
        "startdate": "01-04-2013",
        "enddate": "10-07-2013"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "navn": "Vind et TV",
        "udgiver": "El-giganten",
        "beskrivelse": "Vind et 60\" LED tv til stuen",
        "tilmeldte": 22,
        "startdate": "01-04-2013",
        "enddate": "22-07-2013"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "navn": "Vind en telefon",
        "udgiver": "Samsung",
        "beskrivelse": "Vind en Galaxy S4 4g telefon",
        "tilmeldte": 784,
        "startdate": "10-04-2013",
        "enddate": "30-07-2013"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "navn": "Gratis Vand",
        "udgiver": "Aqua D'or",
        "beskrivelse": null,
        "tilmeldte": 345,
        "startdate": "01-03-2013",
        "enddate": "18-07-2013"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "navn": "Fri Adwords",
        "udgiver": "Google",
        "beskrivelse": null,
        "tilmeldte": 22,
        "startdate": "10-02-2013",
        "enddate": "22-08-2013"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "navn": "Morgenmads produkter",
        "udgiver": "Kellogs",
        "beskrivelse": null,
        "tilmeldte": 111,
        "startdate": "01-05-2013",
        "enddate": "10-09-2013"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "navn": null,
        "udgiver": "Jack & Jones",
        "beskrivelse": null,
        "tilmeldte": 33,
        "startdate": "03-05-2013",
        "enddate": "01-10-2013"
    }
]
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Is you PHP file actually encoded in UTF-8? By the way: JSON’s media type is `application/json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

å is outside the range of ASCII, and therefore must be properly utf8-encoded. Try something like this:

```
"beskrivelse"=>utf8_encode("Vind et....")
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick however do you know how i can avoid the: " When ever my string is printed out it adds the qoutes

Comment: The UTF-8 encoded `å` (0xC3A5) is also out of the range of ASCII (0x00–0x7F).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to encode an array containing non-utf values, you'll get null values in the resulting JSON string.  You can batch-encode all the elements of an array with the array_map function:

```
<?php
$encodedArray = array_map(utf8_encode, $rawArray);
?>
```